# The use of "help" in the passive

Tags: passive-voice

People were helped during the flood.
If I rewrite the sentence as "Everyone was helped during the flood", is it exactly the same as the original one ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you add some detail about why you are asking? Right now, both of those are grammatically correct, but have different meanings. Also, if you wondering about active vs passive, it's not in your question.

Comment: What I'd like to know is whether the two sentences are exactly the same or not.

Comment: @yethu, Karen already told you, "but have different meanings".

Comment: "everyone" means *all* of the people. *people* by itself does not specify a quantity. It could be all of them but more likely just some of them.

Comment: You can rephrase it as **They were helped during the food.**

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is the second one means that **everyone** there would be helped, but the first one doesn't necessarily mean everyone was helped. 3 people could have been helped, 10 people could have been helped, 2,000 people could have been helped. All that the first one means is that some amount of people were helped. And the second one means that everyone in the flood was helped (it's a specific amount)